# Is the heat transfer through a stair case like slab limited by the thinnest region

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

There is a slab with decreasing thickness from left to right and it is all formed by the same material, i.e., the same thermal conductivity. The left side is connected to a heat reservoir and the right is to a heat sink (room temperature). Is the total heat flux only limited by the region with the smallest thickness? If not, what would the heat transfer or temperature profile be like?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! This site doesn't allow for answers to be provided for homework-like questions. Use [Fourier's law of conduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier's_law) (heat flux $q=-kA(x)\frac{dT}{dx}$) and integrate to find the temperature distribution and then the heat flux. The procedure is widely discussed online ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYgp7ToEZqg&ab_channel=MichelvanBiezen)); search for `thermal conduction linear changing cross section`, for instance.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Isn't the heat flux equal to $\dot q/A$ whereas $\dot q$ is the rate of heat transfer?

Comment: Sorry, replace "flux" with "transfer rate." The units are watts (in SI).

Comment: Could you add a sketch of the layout of your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heat flux, also referred to as the heat flow rate intensity, is the amount of energy transfer in the form of heat per unit area per unit time, or heat flux = $\dot q/A$.

For steady heat flow between two thermal reservoirs, where the rate of heat transfer is $-\dot q$ for the hot reservoir and equals the rate of heat transfer of $+\dot q$ to the cold reservoir (for conservation of energy), the rate of heat transfer has to be constant. Since the cross sectional area for your slab varies along its length, the heat flux must also vary for a given heat rate, being a minimum at the left (thick) end and a maximum at the right (thin end).

To my knowledge, the term "total heat flux" has no meaning for a variable thickness slab. On the other hand, I suppose one can calculate the average heat flux along the length of the slab which would be then be the same value as the heat flux for a slab of uniform thickness having the same total thermal resistance.

The electrical analogy is current (analogous to heat flow rate) vs. current density (analogous to heat flux). The current only depends on the potential difference (analogous to temperature difference) between two points and total electrical resistance (analogous to total thermal resistance) between the two points.  The current density at any given cross section is the current divided by the area of the cross section. For a resistor of non uniform thickness, the current density will vary. But the current will be the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It's very helpful. In your answer, you mentioned that it "be the same value as the heat flux for a slab of ...". I have a follow-up question. If we assume the heat conductivity is temperature independent, this is equivalent to treating any irregularly-shaped slab as a slab with a uniform thickness and the same total volume. But if the conductivity is temperature dependent, this treatment is not valid because the temperature profile for the two cases is not the same. Is my statement correct?

Comment: Your original question stated that the material had the same thermal conductivity. If you are now asking about the situation where the conductivity is temperature dependent, it's a different question you should present in a separate post.

Comment: But before you do so, you should consider answers to your question as originally stated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have accepted your answer and asked a separate question with the following link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/734109/349335. I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look and share your perspective.

Comment: @usr01 I’ll take a look at it

Comment: @usr01 took a look at your post. The differential heat equation is complex enough when the thermal conductivity is constant. In any case I feel it is more an exercise in mathematics than physics