# Thermal conduction with changing shape and temperatured dependent thermal conductivity

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I asked a [simpler version](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734075/is-the-heat-transfer-through-a-stair-case-like-slab-limited-by-the-thinnest-regi) of this question earlier and some of the comments are very helpful, especially the youtube tutorials that talk about the case where the [cross-section area](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYgp7ToEZqg&list=PLX2gX-ftPVXVRFXSBIxaCbrp2nHDzg_k7&index=16&ab_channel=MichelvanBiezen) and the [thermal conductivity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvIXqa4cO7s&list=PLX2gX-ftPVXVRFXSBIxaCbrp2nHDzg_k7&index=17&ab_channel=MichelvanBiezen) changes linearly as a function of x. Let's say in a more realistic scenario, I have a metal bar with the same material all the way. The cross-section area changes linearly as a function of x with the relation of `A=10+x`, while the thermal conductivity depends on the local temperature instead of changing linearly with x, and the relationship is `k=10+T`, where `T` is the local temperature.

My question is, for such a complicated case, is it possible to write a differential equation as given in the [previous videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvIXqa4cO7s&list=PLX2gX-ftPVXVRFXSBIxaCbrp2nHDzg_k7&index=17&ab_channel=MichelvanBiezen) and solve it numerically or do we have to rely on some simulation such as finite elements? If a differential equation can be written, could you give me some hints? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**3D equation.** You can write a PDE for conduction in solids with continuous properties. This equation comes from the energy balance equation and reads

$\dfrac{\partial e}{\partial t} = - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{q}$

being $e$ the energy that (under some assumptions) can be written as $e = \rho c T$ and $\mathbf{q}$ the heat flux vector, that can be written as $\mathbf{q} = - k \nabla T$ if Fourier's law holds. To complete the problem, you need initial and boundary conditions.

**1D equation.** Let's focus now on the 1D dimensional equation we can derive for elongated solid elements, like beams or rods.

- assuming constant density $\rho$ and heat capacity $c$ (that we thus take outside the time derivative),
- after integration on the section of the solid element

$\rho c A \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t} = - \dfrac{\partial (A q)}{\partial x} - Q_{lateral}$,

being $Q_{lateral}$ the heat flux exchanged through the lateral surface of the element. Assuming that the element lateral surface is insulated, $Q_{lateral} = 0$. The 1D expression of Fourier's law reads

$q = - k \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x}$,

and thus the differential equation reads

$\rho c A(x) \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}(x,t) =  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( A(x) k(T) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(   T(x,t) \right) \right)$$\quad, \quad t \in [0, T_{fin}], \quad x \in [x_1, x_2]$

with:

- the initial conditions $T(x,0) = T_0(x)$, $x \in [x_1, x_2]$
- the boundary conditions in $x_1$, $x_2$ for $t \in [0, T_{fin}]$, as an example:

  - prescribed temperature (Dirichlet or essential boundary conditions): $T(x_1,  t) = T_1(t)$
  - prescribed heat flux (Neumann or natural boundary conditions):
    $Aq(x_2, t) = A(x_2) k(T) \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x_2} = Aq_2(t)$.

**Numerical solution.** Despite this equation looks quite complex, it can be solved quite in a easy way using its weak formulation and finite element approach. We can get the weak formulation as

$\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} w(x) \rho c A \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t} +  \int_{\Omega} A k \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x} = w(x_2) Q_2(t)$, $\forall w(x) \in W$.

*(This is just a hint about the numerical method, without explicitly referring to mathematical details, especially about the weak formulation and the test space $W$ the test function $w(x)$ belongs to, and the treatment of the essential boundary conditions)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I assume when the system reaches equilibrium state, it can be further simplified to  $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( A(x) \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x}k(T) \right)$$= 0$. And we would only need the boundary condition about the temperature and T[x=x1] and T[x=x2] to solve this equation, right?

Comment: No, you are wrong.  The equation you wrote in your previous comment is incorrect.  It should read $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(A(x)k(T)\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right)=0$$

Comment: @ChetMiller is right, I messed up with $K(T)$: it's only under the outermost derivative. I'm editing my answer. Now you can see that his equation is the steady version of the equation above, if you put $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the total rate of flow of heat Q is constant.  So we have $$-k(T)A(x)\frac{dT}{dx}=Q$$This separates into $$-k(T)dT=Q\frac{dx}{A(x)}$$Both sides can be integrated.

Comment: Thanks! Could I confirm that the integral limit of T is just the temperatures at the two ends of the metal bar? For example, if one side is 0C and the other side is 100C, the limit would just be from 0 to 100. If that's the case, intuitively, it seems like Q doesn't care about the temperature profile at all. Is there any physical interpretation regarding this?

Comment: "*it seems like Q doesn't care about the temperature profile at all*" As shown, the integral is affected by $k(T)$ at every individual point. This results in $Q$ depending on all the intermediate temperatures, not just the boundary conditions.

Comment: The temperature gradient automatically adjusts to the two end temperatures, the function k(T), and the function A(x), and  so Q is intimately related to the temperature profile.  You tell me Q and the temperature at one of the ends, and I'll tell you the entire temperature profile.